# How to use href attribute in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a < href > attributes in my .cshtml page at mvc4 @cp.Name
in my mvc 4 .... what i need is if a person clicks the above link . i have to redirect him to any of the ActionName in Controller (for eg: Index in HomeController )...... how to do it. In my above sample i have redirected to google.com...... but i need to redirect to any of actionname in controller......
My code:

```
<nav> @{ List<MenuRazor.Models.MenuItem> menulist = ViewBag.Menu; } 
<ul id="menu">  
    @foreach (var mp in menulist.Where(p => p.ParentMenu_Id == 0)) {
    <li> <a href="#">@mp.Name</a> 
        @if (menulist.Count(p => p.ParentMenu_Id == mp.Id) > 0)
        { @:<ul> }  
          @RenderMenuItem(menulist, mp)  
          @if (menulist.Count(p => p.ParentMenu_Id == mp.Id) > 0){@:</ul> } 
    </li> } 
</ul> 

@helper RenderMenuItem(List<MenuRazor.Models.MenuItem> menuList, MenuRazor.Models.MenuItem mi) 
{
    foreach (var cp in menuList.Where(p => p.ParentMenu_Id == mi.Id)) {
        @:<li> <a href="http://codeproject.com">@cp.Name</a> 

        if (menuList.Count(p => p.ParentMenu_Id == cp.Id) > 0) { 
            @:<ul> 
        } 
        @RenderMenuItem(menuList, cp) 
        if (menuList.Count(p => p.ParentMenu_Id == cp.Id) > 0) { 
           @:</ul> 
        } else  { 
           @:</li> 
        }  
} }   </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Html.ActionLink` or `@Url.Action` to generated you link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link name", "Action", "Controller", new { id = your_param }, null)
```

or

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")
```

The `@Html.ActionLink` might better suit your current problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")`

Refer this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) link for more information.